# How to add custom modifier for Text?

Tags: swift, swiftui

So far I am able to write custom modifiers for Views; however, when trying to keep my code DRY, I am trying to add a custom modifier for TextFields. The view modifiers work great with something like so:

```swift
struct sampleModifier : ViewModifier {
    var height: CGFloat? = 100
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .frame(height: height)
            .background(Color.white)
            .border(Color.gray, width: 0.5)
            .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 15, x: 0, y: 10)
    }
}
```

But when I try to use modifiers like `font` and so, it shows a lot of errors. I do understand that they might need to be more specific and instead conform to the `TextFieldStyleModifier`, but I do not get how to make it work. I have tried to do it this way without success:

```swift
struct TitleModifier : TextFieldStyleModifier {
    func body(content: TextFieldStyle) -> some View {
        content
            .font(.custom("Open Sans", size: 18))
            .color(Color.green)
            
    }
}
```

Which obviously fails and shows the following error:
[image: Error]

If I click on the `Fix` suggestion, it adds this to my code

```swift
TextFieldStyleModifier<<#Style: TextFieldStyle#>>
```

Which I do not know how to use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Same question on the Apple Developer Forums - https://developers.apple.com/forums/thread/658297.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TextFields are also views, so you create the modifier in the same fashion:

```swift
struct TitleModifier : ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(.custom("Open Sans", size: 18))
            .foregroundColor(Color.green)

    }
}
```

Also note that there is no modifier .color(). It is .foregroundColor().

When you want to apply it to a FormField, you just do:

```swift
TextField("", text: $field1).modifier(TitleModifier())
```

Comment: There is one problem for this ViewModifier. It's not only for Text. What if I only want to apply this modifier to Text?

Comment: Hi @Bagusflyer, sorry I do not get your point. If you don't want to apply the modifier to non-text views, simply don't apply it. What am I missing?

Comment: @Bagusflyer, did you find a solution? I mean how to create custom modifier for Text type

Comment: @kontiki think about the case where you want to apply a modifier that isn't implemented on all Views. What if, for example, shadow didn't work on all views, but did on TextViews. The compiler would not accept the above solution.

Comment: @kontiki Concatenation will not work: Text("1").modifier(TitleModifier()) + Text("2") + Text("3")

Comment: @kontiki The problem I'm coming across is this: Because the custom modifier returns `some View` and not `Text`, I can't chain it together with other text-only modifiers. For example, I can write `Text("some text").bold().myCustomModifier()`, because `myCustomModifier()` applies to any `View`. But I can't write `Text("some text").myCustomModifier().bold()`, b/c `bold()` only applies to `Text`. This limitation means I have to care a lot about the order in which I apply my text modifiers. :(

Answer (score 24):

Right now it is possible to add `.font()` and `.foregroundColor()` modifiers to the `content` inside ViewModifier. However, if you want to add some custom modifiers that can be applied only to a specific view, for example `.strikethrough()` modifier for Text View, you can add these modifiers into the extension.

```
struct TitleModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(.custom("Open Sans", size: 18))
            .foregroundColor(.green)
    }
}

extension Text {
    func customText() -> some View {
        self.strikethrough().bold().italic().lineLimit(4)
            .modifier(TitleModifier())
    }
}
```

Usage `Text("Hello").customText()`.

Comment: I have tried this but getting an error:

Type '() -> some View' cannot conform to 'View'

Comment: Asif Syeed, Can you please write more details, code sample?

Comment: Hey! Later I have implemented by creating an extension of View. Here is the snippet:
https://codeshare.io/K8JEVE

Comment: Asif Syeed thank you for the code snippet. If I change extension of View back to Text, your sample doesn't show an error. You are correctly applying the modifier directly to `Text` and returning `some View`, so it works. Maybe there was some other modifier before custom one, or you tried to return `View` not `some View`, or ViewBuilder was required. Anyway I am glad you've found a suitable solution for your case, if you still have some questions, let me know :)

Answer (score 5):

You can create a  custom TextFieldStyle, this will apply only to TextField, not to other views on the view container

```
struct CustomTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .font(.custom("Open Sans", size: 18))
            .foregroundColor(Color.green)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Group {
    Text("not applied here")
    TextField("applied here", text: $presenter.name)
}
.textFieldStyle(CustomTextFieldStyle())
```

Answer (score 4):

As I know, use a Text extension is much better. For Text, some modifiers are very special, the return body type is not View, but Text. [You can find many here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text).

```
 extension Text {
    func font(size: CGFloat) -> Text { // don't return `some View`
        self.font(Font.custom("Open Sans", size: size))
    }
}
```

This means we defined the type of Content and Body for ViewModifier, not sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

In **Xcode 11 beta 4**, the `color(_:)` modifier is deprecated. So use the `foregroundColor(_:)` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Working with custom fonts**:

- install font in your mac and show font details in font book, use the postscript name all time

[image: postscript name]

- add fonts to app

[image: adding custom fonts]

[image: adding custom fonts]

add `enum`, in a new file:

import SwiftUI

```
enum CustomFonts: String {
        case bold = "Family-Bold", medium = "Family-Medium"
}
```

add extension, in a new file:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Font {
    static func custom(_ font: CustomFonts, size: CGFloat) -> SwiftUI.Font {
        SwiftUI.Font.custom(font.rawValue, size: size)
    }
}
```

use:

```
Text("Hello World")
  .font(.custom(.bold, size: 24))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// MARK: - Text Styles, iOS 15+:

import SwiftUI

struct TextStyle {
    var fontFamily: String = "Roboto Flex"
    let fontSize: CGFloat
    let fontWeight: Font.Weight
    let lineHeight: CGFloat
    var lineSpacing: CGFloat { lineHeight - fontSize }
}

// MARK: - Create our styles:

extension TextStyle {
    static let heading1 = TextStyle(
        fontSize: 36,
        fontWeight: .bold,
        lineHeight: 44
    )
    static let heading2 = TextStyle(
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: .medium,
        lineHeight: 32
    )
}

// MARK: - Create ViewModifier:

fileprivate struct TextStyleModifier: ViewModifier {
    let textStyle: TextStyle

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(
                Font.custom(
                    textStyle.fontFamily,
                    size: textStyle.fontSize
                )
                .weight(textStyle.fontWeight)
            )
            .lineSpacing(textStyle.lineSpacing)
    }
}

// MARK: - Create View extension:

extension View {
    func setStyle(_ textStyle: TextStyle) -> some View {
        modifier(TextStyleModifier(textStyle: textStyle))
    }
}

// MARK: - Usage:

struct TestFont: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Group {
                Text("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and cat")
                    .setStyle(.heading1)
                Text("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and cat")
                    .setStyle(.heading2)
            }
            .padding(10)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Preview:

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestFont()
    }
}
```

[image: Result:]