# In SwiftUI, How can I app-globally predefine font styles?

Tags: swiftui

Given the following code,

```swift
Text("Foobar")
    .font(.largeTitle)
```

…renders the result as so:

[image: a screenshot saying Foobar]

But, I generally want *every* occurrence of `.title`, `.title2` , `.title3` , `.largeTitle` to be inherently of bold weight and a certain color, just like I had defined

```swift
Text("Foobar")
    .font(.largeTitle) // or `.title[2-3]` respectively
    .fontWeight(.bold)
    .foregroundColor(Color("TitleColor"))
```

…so that it looks like this, in my case:

[image: another screenshot]

Otherwise phrased, I'd like to attach the property `.largeTitle` to inherently be also bold and have a particular color. Kind of what I am used to by using CSS.

I could do this, for example,

```swift
/// Decorator for Text() that implies Corporate Design's style
struct TitleText: View {
    let content: String
    let font: Font
    public init(_ content: String, font: Font = .title) {
        self.content = content
        self.font = font
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(content)
            .font(font)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(Color("TitleColor"))
    }
}
```

But that feels superfluous and I like to avoid this to not replicate possible core functionality.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing apples and oranges here in a way, you want a custom font style but color is not a property of `Font` so it's really a view (`Text`) modifier you want.

So a `Font` only modifier could be

```
extension Font {
    static var myLargeTitle: Font {
        Font.system(.largeTitle, weight: .bold)
    }
}
```

Note the change of name here, I don't think it's possible to name it like a predefined style and even if it was I think it would be a bad idea.

Now to include a color as well we need a `Text` modifier as mentioned earlier. Starting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63121366/9223839) we get

```
extension Text {
    func myLargeGreenTitle() -> some View {
        self.font(.myLargeTitle).foregroundColor(.green)
    }
}
```

So now you can either do

```
Text("Custom Font Title")
    .font(.myLargeTitle)
```

Or

```
Text("Custom Font Title")
    .myLargeGreenTitle()
```